# How do I get the Tab key to do what I expect

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Dev Ed has a number of courses on YouTube. I have been viewing on named HTML and CSS Tutorial.

I have Visual Studio Code installed and added the packages suggested in the Tutorial. I get to the point where the `<!DOCTYPE html>` tag has been created and on a new line the tag `<html>` has been typed. This automatically completes the end tag, hence `<html></html>`. If I am understanding this correctly, Ed then says hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key but it just produces spacing as you would normally expect with a <kbd>Tab</kbd>. 
My expectation is that it formats the code as follows:

```html
<html>

</html>
```

This does not happen.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense

Comment: By "VSC" do you mean Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Yes. VSC == Visual Studio Code

Comment: Please keep in mind, if one of the answers works for you, please mark them as the answer to help other peeps in the community to find their solution easier if they facing the same issue. If you don't know how to do it please read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1):

According to [VSCode release notes](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v0_3_0#_html), **such a feature has been removed from the IntelliSense** and replaced with `</`.

In order to autocomplete your tags you can do either of these:

1. Use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> to select from provided items in the suggestion list.
2. Use third party plugins like [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag).

Answer (score 0):

Save your file as `.html` or if already have done that, click on the text between CRLF and smiley face and select HTML

[image: VS code screenshot]

Comment: I do not see the line with JavaScript and a Smiley Face so I am at a loss as to what next. Probably start over and reinstall Virtual Studio Code and follow the HTML CSS Course Tutorial by Ed Dev to see if I have missed something.

Comment: can you please provide a screenshot?

Comment: I have decided to give up on this. The problem is not auto Tag completion - that works. This is to do with Keyboard Mapping. The commands I see are different from those in the Tutorial I have been attempting to complete.